# How to check if a JSON post request contains a certain key and update the JSON file in Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, express

So I am making an API to check if a Minecraft server is online or not. I am using express and bodyParser and using a JSON file to store the status. I am sending a POST request to the server and want to make sure that the POST request body is sending the right key.

This is my current code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync('serverStatus.json');
var status = JSON.parse(data);
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const cors = require('cors');

app.get('/status', alldata);
function alldata(request, response) {
    response.send(status);
}

app.post('/status', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.is('application/json')) {
        res.status(500);
        res.send('500 - Server Error');
    } else {
        res.status(201);
        res.send(req.body);
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(`Server running on: http://localhost:${PORT}`)
);
```

and this is my test JSON file:

```
{
    "survival": "online",
    "creative": "online"
}
```

Is there also an easy way to update the JSON file to edit the original server statuses?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values in the JSON object using the object's keys:

```
req.body.key
```

or

```
req.body['key']
```

If the JSON object doesn't contain that key, it will return `undefined`

To assign a value, you can use the same logic:

```
req.body.key = value
```

This will update the original object, so you can return `req.body` and it will contain the new value.